# Keil v5.38a on win 10 pro - Runtime error R6002 Floating point support not loaded and Internal fault

Tags: keil

I've installed MDK 5.38a on Windows 10 64 bits.
The first compilation of test prog runs great, but next time or after creating a new project a get two errors.
If I use compiler ver 5 (5.06 update7) I get

> Runtime error R6002 - floating point support not loaded

but when I switch to compiler ver 6 first compilation runs OK but as upper on the next compilation I get

> Internal fault [0x4c07bf:6190004]

What is wrong, where is the problem? I try to install MDK on a clean Windows installation and it is still the same.

I reinstalled Windows, and Keil MDK, and nothing, the errors came back.